# Sending multiple data and receiving it though post in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, session

This is my code to post data

```
    $scope.res=function(fina){
        $scope.total= $scope.output;
        $scope.finals=angular.copy($scope.fina);
        $http.post('/submit', {order: $scope.finals,total:   $scope.total}).success(function(data){
            alert(data);        
            $scope.finals=data;

            });
            };  

        //load_groups();    

    $http.get('http://localhost:3070/submit').success(function(data){
        alert("here too");
            $scope.finals=data;

    });
```

Can I post order and total in the same post? If yes how can I access it in get??

This is my app.get code. How do I send total in this?

```
app.get('/submit', function (req, res){
//TODO check that the data is valid before just using it

return res.json( req.session.order);

});
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do here ? Are you trying to sending some data in a GET request for which you're using POST now ?

Comment: Basically when i refresh a page the data should not get lost. So i am posting the data. And getting the same data back using get call. This works for orders. I need it to work for orders and total.